# Finite dimensional skew fields over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, division-algebras

Is there a specific reference for finite dimensional, associative, unital $\mathbb{Q}-$algebras that are division rings? Or also more in general, the type of questions I am trying to look into are:

How does the tensor product (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of two such rings look like? What is its center, depending on the centers of the two rings? Can I construct the compositum of two such rings and look at their intersection in there? How does it behave? What can be said about the Jacobson radical of such rings? How does the commutator of a subalgebra behave? What if the subalgebra is also a division ring? What is the commutator of the commutator? ...

I am particularly interested in knowing how the **dimensions** of all these $\mathbb{Q}-$algebras relate to one another. Any (not too general) reference or partial answer is appreciated.

Comment: Searching for "rational division algebra" is certainly a natural thing to do. I did that and got a few promising hits, but I can't really use them to answer your question.

Comment: This is all well known, and has been for (I suppose) about 80 years. Your search term should be “Brauer group”. The fact is that there are finite-dimensional division rings of every possible dimension, whose center is $\Bbb Q$ itself: these are called “central division algebras over $\Bbb Q$. The “possible dimensions” are $n^2$ for $n\ge2$. For instance, those of dimension $4$ are called quaternion algebras, and there are countably many non-isomorphic such.

Comment: I think there is a typo in @Lubin's comment.  What he means is there is a skew field (many in fact) of dimension $dn^2$ whose center is a degree $d$ extension of $\mathbb Q$ for every $n$.  For a survey of the classification, you can see my notes on quaternion algebras, for instance, and I give references that have complete proofs.

Comment: What you say is right, @Kimball, but I intentionally wrote what I wrote, ’cause OP was asking about $\Bbb Q$-algebras, and I (perhaps erroneously) assumed he had central $\Bbb Q$-algebras in mind.

Comment: @Lubin Maybe I just misparsed what you wrote:  when you said "every possible dimension" I was thinking $dn^2$, whereas now I guess you meant every _square_ dimension happens for central simple algebras.

Comment: At least I told no lie, contrary to my frequent behavior.

Comment: I do not assume the algebras to be central over $\mathbb{Q}$. But thanks to both for your helpful comments!